# F# pattern matching with string

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

```
let rec matchs str currList =
    match currList with 
    | [] -> []
    | (str, _) as hd :: tl -> hd :: matchs str tl
    | _::tl -> matchs str tl
```

I have my function here, and when i try to execute it with this line:

```
matchs "A" [("A",5); ("BB",6); ("AA",9); ("A",0)];;
```

This is the given output

```
val it : (string * int) list = [("A", 5); ("BB", 6); ("AA", 9); ("A", 0)]
```

I am not understanding why its not giving me only the tuples matching "A"

eventually i would want my output to be

```
val it : int list = [0; 5]
```

Comment: Your `str` identifier used in second match case is not the same as `str` parameter passed to function. It's not comparison. You basically shadow function parameter with new variable having the same name. If you want to compare value with variable in match case use `| (a, b)::tail when a = str -> `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: you can't match on variable content, only on literals and constructors (well, and active patterns).

---

This match case:

```
| (str, _) as hd :: tl ->
```

Contrary to your intuition, it doesn't match only tuples that have `str` as first component. Instead, it matches *any* tuples, and then it binds those tuples' first component to name `str`, shadowing the function parameter of the same name.

Here's a simplified version of this problem:

```
let x = 42
let y = 5

match y with
| x -> printfn "%d" x
| _ -> printfn "not equal to x"
```

This code would print out "5", not "42". And you get a compiler warning that the second match case will never be reached.

---

If you want only tuples with `str` first component, you can use a `when` guard with your pattern:

```
| (s, _) as hd :: tl when s == str ->
```