# In F#, how to use Array.Pick on strings?

Tags: f#

(Newbie question).

In F#, please assume an array of CompanyNames of the format:

*"BLUE CROSS BLUE SHIELD OF ALABAMA, BIRMINGHAM"*

This from the below where GetAllCompanies reads from the database the company names and cities:

```
CompanyNames = GetAllCompanies |> Array.map (fun i -> sprintf "%s , %s" i.companyname i.city )
```

This fails, but is my best attempt at going the other way. That is, given the company name and city as a string like above, I want to get back the company it came from (y is the company,city string from above):

```
let company = Array.pick (fun (k:company1) ->
              match sprintf "%s , %s" k.companyname k.city with
              | y -> Some k
              | _ -> None ) GetAllCompanies
```

The compiler gives the warning on _ as: *"This rule will never be matched".*

How is this done?

TIA

Just to clarify,  I will be getting a string of "company name"+","+"city" as typed in by the user. I need to check if this string matches a composite string of "company name"+","+"city" that was built from the company details and then return all the company details when it matches. GetAllCompanies returns an array of company details. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177879/180286

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've read that answer multiple times before posting this question. I don't understand how it applies to my situation. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: What it means is that the match-with doesn't have anything to test against on the first case, since you're simply naming the result `y`, and then returning `Some k`. Since `y` matches and catches everything, the `_` can never be hit. Both `y` and `_` are meant to be used last in a match-with.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking the wrong question. It seems you're trying to find the first company that matches the user input. Unless you want to transform the found company, Array.pick is not the right function, and you should use another function. You probably also don't want an exception if the company is not found.

```
type Company = { Name: string; City: string }

let companies =
    [|
        { Name = "Foo"; City = "Oslo"}
        { Name = "Bar"; City = "Lillehammer"}
    |]
    
let userInput = "Bar,Lillehammer"

let company =
    companies
    |> Array.tryFind (fun c -> c.Name + "," + c.City = userInput)
```

Now you can match on company.

There are still several weaknesses. Two of them: What if several companies match the user input? I'd use Array.filter then, if you want to present all of them to the user during interactive input. What if the user types spaces, e.g. a space after the comma? Or if there are commas in the company info?

Comment: You are so so CORRECT! However, in this situation, I am insisting the primary database key is unique on (companyname,city). In hindsight, I probably should reduce the input string to a tuple on companyname and city, then do a pick on that. But I did want to learn how to use "pick" on strings. (I'm very much still learning :)  Thanks.

Comment: Are you on F# Slack? It's much better suited for learning and long discussions about things like this, and you get quick answers and followup. There's a few thousand of us, including the biggest names in the F# community. SO is primarily good for Q and A, but its format is not that ideal for learning and discussions.